# Excel search, find, copy paste macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro enabled workbook with 2 sheets. The first Sheet(Sheet1) has 3 columns, UPC, Item Name. The second sheet consists of two cells which are already formatted to my liking. My end goal is for a macro button on Sheet1 to ask for a user input. This user input will be a UPC. I would like for the macro to then search for the UPC which are in cell ranges A2:A10000. Afterwards I would like the corresponding item name(all item names are B2:B10000 on Sheet1) to the UPC to be pasted on cell A1:A2 (cells are conjoined) of Sheet2. Then the price(All Prices are on C2:C10000 of Sheet1) of the corresponding UPC from Sheet1 to be pasted on A3 of Sheet 2 . Also as a cherry on top, I want to be able to maximize the font size in the cells on sheet 2 for a 2.25 in x 1.25 in label. Please and Thank you, I would truly appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: So, have you started with the record macro function? How did that pan out? Or have you looked on here for codes that do similar things? Then you can edit them to match what you need.

Comment: I tried the record macro function, but it doesnt allow for variables in terms of user input for finding the UPC. So in that case, I am looking for code. Thank you for taking your time to respond.

Comment: No, once you have something recorded, YOU have to add the variables that you need - the record macro cannot guess that for you.

Comment: Ok so how would I go about recording what I want? Should I record me doing the cmd-f and then selecting the corresponding Item Name and Price?

Comment: Are the UPC Item Name's unique?

Comment: All UPC's have a unique Item Name, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the 'UPC Items' are unique, I feel you are overcomplicating things with vba code.

I would get the user to type the UPC item number into an empty cell, let's say they type it into cell D1 on sheet 2.

On cells A1 (sheet 2) write a vlookup formula:

=VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$10000,2,FALSE)

and on cells A3 (Sheet) 2) write this vlookup formula:

=VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$10000,3,FALSE)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I added an easy print macro. I linked a database for the price list and UPC, which auto updates. Now this workbook is a fully functioning label printer. I appreciate your help.